# After a glancing collision, why do air hockey pucks spins around in circle?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

For a lab testing the conservation of momentum, I had to hit an air hockey puck so that it would hit another stationary puck in a glancing collision. After the pucks collided, they travel their separate ways, but I also noticed that both pucks seem to be spinning in circles as they travel on. This spinning had no effect on movement, as both pucks were only traveling in straight lines throughout the experiment. I did this a few more times and it happened every time I repeated it. What could have caused the pucks to be spinning in circles when all I did was hit one puck straight on, which then collide with the other puck?

Comment: Are you saying the first puck (that collides head on) is spinning, or just the ones the hit at a glancing angle (which would give a tangential friction force and this explain the spinning)?

Answer (score 3):

If the collision is not perfectly along the line connecting the centers of mass of the pucks, they will exert torques on each other as well as forces. The angular momentum of the pair will be conserved, so if the incoming puck was not spinning, the pucks will exit the collision spinning in opposite directions. If the surface they slide on is frictionless, the spinning will not affect the translational motion.

[image: Hockey pucks colliding off-center]

Comment: Wouldn't the linear momentum decrease since angular momentum is generated?

Comment: No, they are different quantities, and are conserved separately. The spinning of an object about its center of mass contributes nothing to the linear momentum.

Comment: Where does the energy for the change in angular momentum come from? Since the 2 disks are spinning in opposite directions, then the sum of angular momentum is same, but energy had to come from somewhere to make the change. The only energy I can see is the kinetic energy from the sliding disk.

Comment: That's right. It just like comparing the speeds of a rolling ball, a rolling cylinder, or a frictionless, sliding cube at the bottom of an inclined plane, starting from rest. The cube will have the greatest speed, then the ball, then the cylinder. They all have the same energy, but different speeds because of the rotational motion and moments of inertia.

Comment: I would still like to know where the energy came from to get the disks spinning.

Comment: The translational kinetic energy of the incoming puck is distributed to the translational and rotational energies of each puck (if the collision is perfectly elastic).

Comment: So the original kinetic momentum is greater than the final kinetic momentum?

Comment: What is kinetic momentum? Linear momentum is conserved, and angular momentum is conserved.  Kinetic energy may or may not be conserved but total energy is conserved. Also, there is a difference between conservation and constancy.

Comment: My mistake, I mislabeled the momentum; but I though it would be apparent that I meant the momentum from movement. But it still does make any sense that you have more energy in the system after collision than before. You have constant linear momentum, and 2 angular momentums (that cancel out) and no explanation on how the disks got the energy to spin.

Comment: Yes, I did. The kinetic energy of the incoming puck is redistributed to the kinetic energies of the the pucks after the collision. Whether the energy is due to rotation or translation is irrelevant. Energy is not a vector. The momenta are.  And I never said there was *more* energy.